# Set permanent environment variable for a folder

Tags: environment-variables

There are a lot of duplicate questions about setting permanent environment variables, but no questions about setting them for a specific folder.

So, how to set an environment variable for a specific folder?

Clearifying: I want my `CUSTOM_ENV_VAR` to activate only when i work in a specific dir `.../custom_dir/`. So when i launch programs in the folder, programs use this `CUSTOM_ENV_VAR`, when i launch outside - programs do not use it.

Comment: @steeldriver I understand this, but isn't there a way to tell the process to load variable only when the user works in a special directory?

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav see [Thomas Ward's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056382/178692) - I guess in principle you could use the bash `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check `pwd` and set / unset variables (our source environment scripts) appropriately

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Using `direnv`

Install `direnv`, which is a tool for this purpose which is a statically linked executable that hooks into your shell (csh,bash, and the like)

```
sudo apt-get install direnv && echo "eval "$(direnv hook bash)"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now to whichever folder you'd like the environment variables to be set, add an `.direnvrc` file that must have valid bash syntax. For example of your case, you can load both pyenv's version management as well as your own variables by setting your `.direnvrc` to:

```
use_python() {
  local python_root=$PYENV_ROOT/versions/$1
  load_prefix "$python_root"
  if [[ -x "$python_root/bin/python" ]]; then
    layout python "$python_root/bin/python"
  else
    echo "Error: $python_root/bin/python can't be executed."
    exit
  fi
}
export CUSTOM_VAR="xyz";
```

You can see other examples at their [wiki](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki)

<sub><sup>Thanks to [@ChrisKuehl](https://askubuntu.com/users/850195/chris-kuehl) in the comments for the suggestion</sup></sub>

---

Another alternate approach would be to override the `PROMPT_COMMAND` (as suggested in the comments by [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)) to point to a function that loads your environment variable up, by adding something like this to your `.bashrc`

```
prmfn() {
  if [ "$PWD" == "yourdirectorypath" ]; then
    export CUSTOM_ENV_VAR=value
  else
    unset CUSTOM_ENV_VAR
  fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=prmfn
```

Now when you enter `yourdirectorypath`, it'll automatically set `CUSTOM_ENV_VAR`, when you exit out of it, it'll `unset`(remove) the variable, hence that variable is only available when the current directory is `yourdirectorypath`

Comment: Seems like it works, but is there a simplier solution? For example if i use pyenv for my directory, can the var be set automaticly with pyenv?

Comment: There are a fair number of tools that generalize the approach in this answer and seem to achieve what you're looking for, e.g. [aactivator](https://github.com/yelp/aactivator) or [direnv](https://direnv.net/).